# Accessing data inside compose function Ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I'm using a Ramda to give structure to some data. However, I have been unable to access the data inside the `compose`.

1. It should map items with a `level` greater than 2, but this did not work

`[keys, compose(map(map(find(propEq('level', > 2)))), values)]`

2. I am trying to keep all items inside `typeChild` as `unique`.

Here is the ramda console to test it out (got to follow link through there, SO won't allow goo.gl links): http://dpaste.com/0SATTZK

```
const result = pipe(
  pluck('type'),
  groupBy(
    pipe(
      find(propEq('level', 1)),
      propOr('NoLevel', 'name'),
    )
  ),
  converge(
    zipWith(unapply(zipObj(['name', 'typeChild']))),
    [keys, compose(map(map(find(propEq('level', 2)))), values)]
  ),
);
result(data)
```

## Input data

```
[{
    "title": "Apple",
    "type": [{"name": "Food", "level": 1}, {"name": "Fruit", "level": 2}]
  }, {
    "title": "Tomato",
    "type": [{"name": "Food", "level": 1}, {"name": "Fruit", "level": 2}]
  }, {
    "title": "Potato",
    "type": [{"name": "Food", "level": 1}, {"name": "Vegetable", "level": 2}]
  }, {
    "title": "The Alchemist",
    "type": [{"name": "Entertainment", "level": 1}, { "name": "Book", "level": 2}]
  }, {
    "title": "Superman",
    "type": [{"name": "Entertainment", "level": 1}, {"name": "Movie", "level": 2}]
  }, {
    "title": "More facts",
    "type": [{"name": "Foo", "level": 2}]
  }, {
    "title": "Superman",
    "type": [{"name": "Bar", "level": 1}]
  }
];
```

## Desired output

[

```
{name: "Food", typechild: [{level: 2, name: "Fruit"}, {level: 2, name: "Vegetable"}]},
 {name: "Entertainment", typechild: [{level: 2, name: "Book"}, {level: 2, name: "Movie"}]},
 {name: "NoName", typechild: [{level: 2, name: "Foo"}]},
 {name: "Bar", typechild: []}
]
```

Comment: Please include some description of the data structure in the question itself.  The external link is fine as additional information, but the question should be able to stand by itself.

Comment: I have several questions.  (1) what do you mean by "*access the data* inside the `compose`"?  (2) What do you want to filter on? (goo .gl /VuBdR5) has both `propEq('level', 1)` and `propEq('level', 2)`, but nothing like `propEq('level', > 2)` (not actual JS anyway.)  (3) (and most fundamentally), what are you trying to do in general?  I know you want to change the shape of your data, but what are you filtering out, and what shape will the remainder have?  Do you mind losing the 'title' property entirely, which happens when the first step of your `compose`/`pipe` is `pluck('type')`?

Comment: Updated the question for clarify, but thanks for the great response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I'm going to make a guess at what you're looking for.

---

### Show me the data

First of all, you really need to demonstrate some part of your input data.  I reduced it to this:

```
const data =[{
    "title": "Apple",
    "type": [{"name": "Food", "level": 1}, {"name": "Fruit", "level": 2}]
  }, {
    "title": "Tomato",
    "type": [{"name": "Food", "level": 1}, {"name": "Fruit", "level": 2}]
  }, {
    "title": "Potato",
    "type": [{"name": "Food", "level": 1}, {"name": "Vegetable", "level": 2}]
  }, {
    "title": "The Alchemist",
    "type": [{"name": "Entertainment", "level": 1}, { "name": "Book", "level": 2}]
  }, {
    "title": "Superman",
    "type": [{"name": "Entertainment", "level": 1}, {"name": "Movie", "level": 2}]
  }, {
    "title": "More facts",
    "type": [{"name": "Foo", "level": 2}]
  }, {
    "title": "Superman",
    "type": [{"name": "Bar", "level": 1}]
  }
];
```

(Note that I removed the `color` properties from each type as they don't seem relevant to the discussion, but they wouldn't change anything.)

And I'm guessing from your attempt that output something like this would be desired:

```
[
 {name: "Food", typechild: [{level: 2, name: "Fruit"}, {level: 2, name: "Vegetable"}]},
 {name: "Entertainment", typechild: [{level: 2, name: "Book"}, {level: 2, name: "Movie"}]},
 {name: "NoName", typechild: [{level: 2, name: "Foo"}]},
 {name: "Bar", typechild: []}
]
```

### Approaching this by composing functions

Here is one approach:

```
const levelEq = (n) => pipe(prop('level'), equals(n));
const topLevel = pipe(prop('type'), find(levelEq(1)));
const topLevelName = pipe(topLevel, propOr('NoName', 'name'));
const extract2ndLevel = pipe(pluck('type'), flatten, filter(levelEq(2)));

const convert = pipe(
  groupBy(topLevelName),
  map(extract2ndLevel),
  map(uniq),
  toPairs,
  map(zipObj(['name', 'typechild']))
);

convert(data); //=> (the first output format above)
```

(Usually for those one-liners, instead of `pipe`, I would use `compose`, and reverse the order, but I also don't much like mixing `compose` and `pipe` in the same script.  I definitely prefer `pipe` for the longer `convert` function.  But switching any of these, or combining them would not change anything essential.)

The point is that this is built on *function composition*.  Rather than trying to build it all at once, I write separate functions to do small jobs and combine them into more complex ones.

Note that this code will not gracefully handle bad data, and changing to do that might be a significant chore.

Note also that in the main function, I work one small step at a time.  I can comment out subsequent steps to see the result of each individual step.  I could also use [`R.tap`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#tap) if I liked.

### Re-combining rarely a good idea

Each of those helper functions, except for the relatively simple `levelEq` is used only once.  So they could be easily inlined.  We could rewrite this code like this:

```
const convert = pipe(
  groupBy(pipe(prop('type'), find(pipe(prop('level'), equals(1))), propOr('NoName', 'name'))),
  map(pipe(pluck('type'), flatten, filter(pipe(prop('level'), gte(__, 2))), uniq)),
  toPairs,
  map(zipObj(['name', 'typechild']))
);
```

But to me that is an unreadable mess, and I wouldn't bother.

### Better Documentation

If you are used to the [Hindley-Milnar style type annotation](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki/Type-Signatures), it might help to add type signatures to these functions, perhaps something like:

```
// Type :: {name: String, level: Int}

// :: Int -> (Type -> Bool)
const levelEq = (n) => pipe(prop('level'), equals(n));
// :: {type: [Type]} -> Type
const topLevel = pipe(prop('type'), find(levelEq(1)));
// :: {type: [Type]} -> String
const topLevelName = pipe(topLevel, propOr('NoName', 'name'));
// :: [{title: String, type: [Type}]}] -> [Type]
const extract2ndLevel = pipe(pluck('type'), flatten, filter(levelEq(2)));

// [{title: String, type: [Type]}] -> [{name: String, typechild: [Type]}]
const convert = pipe( /* ... */ )
```

(If these mean nothing to you, don't worry about it.)

### Changing Output Format

But perhaps you really want something like this:

```
[
 {"name": "Food", "typechild": ["Fruit", "Vegetable"]}, 
 {"name": "Entertainment", "typechild": ["Book", "Movie"]}, 
 {"name": "NoName", "typechild": ["Foo"]}, 
 {"name": "Bar", "typechild": []}
]
```

This turns out to be a simple change:

```
const convert = pipe(
  groupBy(topLevelName),
  map(extract2ndLevel),
  map(uniq),
  map(pluck('name')), // <--- A single addition
  toPairs,
  map(zipObj(['name', 'typechild']))
);
```

### Advantages of `map`

One thing we see in that last snippet is a sequence of consecutive `map` calls.  Each of those is looping over the list separately.  This makes for clean code, but if in your performance testing, you found that this additional looping was causing your problems, you could take advantage of the [composition law associated with map](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#functor), which, suitably translated, says that

```
pipe(map(f), map(g)) ≍ map(pipe(f, g))
```

So you could add this:

```
// :: [{title: String, type: [Type}]}] -> [String]
const foo = pipe(extract2ndLevel, uniq, pluck('name'));
```

And rewrite the main function like this:

```
// [{title: String, type: [Type]}] -> [{name: String, typechild: [Type]}]
const convert = pipe(
  groupBy(topLevelName),
  map(foo),
  toPairs,
  map(zipObj(['name', 'typechild']))
);
```

But the fact that I can't think of a good name for this new function makes me think that it's not a great abstraction; I would only choose to do this if actual performance testing demonstrated that the multiple iterations were a real-world problem.

### Conclusion

Functional programming is about many things, but one of the key techniques is a relentless breaking down of everything into easily understood pieces.  That's what I try to do with this solution.  While we can break this to create single functions without dependencies (*"Recombining..." above*) that is rarely readable.  On the other hand, this approach made it easy to alter our approach (*"Change Output formats"*), and, if necessary, to fix performance problems (*"Advantages of `map`"*).

Wow, that should have been a blog post!

---

You can see much of this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20data%20%3D%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22title%22%3A%20%22Apple%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%20%22Food%22%2C%20%22level%22%3A%201%7D%2C%20%7B%22name%22%3A%20%22Fruit%22%2C%20%22level%22%3A%202%7D%5D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22title%22%3A%20%22Tomato%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%20%22Food%22%2C%20%22level%22%3A%201%7D%2C%20%7B%22name%22%3A%20%22Fruit%22%2C%20%22level%22%3A%202%7D%5D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22title%22%3A%20%22Potato%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%20%22Food%22%2C%20%22level%22%3A%201%7D%2C%20%7B%22name%22%3A%20%22Vegetable%22%2C%20%22level%22%3A%202%7D%5D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22title%22%3A%20%22The%20Alchemist%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%20%22Entertainment%22%2C%20%22level%22%3A%201%7D%2C%20%7B%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Book%22%2C%20%22level%22%3A%202%7D%5D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22title%22%3A%20%22Superman%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%20%22Entertainment%22%2C%20%22level%22%3A%201%7D%2C%20%7B%22name%22%3A%20%22Movie%22%2C%20%22level%22%3A%202%7D%5D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22title%22%3A%20%22More%20facts%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%20%22Foo%22%2C%20%22level%22%3A%202%7D%5D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22title%22%3A%20%22Superman%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%20%22Bar%22%2C%20%22level%22%3A%201%7D%5D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%5D%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Type%20%3A%3A%20%7Bname%3A%20String%2C%20level%3A%20Int%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20%3A%3A%20Int%20-%3E%20%28Type%20-%3E%20Bool%29%0Aconst%20levelEq%20%3D%20%28n%29%20%3D%3E%20pipe%28prop%28%27level%27%29%2C%20equals%28n%29%29%3B%0A%2F%2F%20%3A%3A%20%7Btype%3A%20%5BType%5D%7D%20-%3E%20Type%0Aconst%20topLevel%20%3D%20pipe%28prop%28%27type%27%29%2C%20find%28levelEq%281%29%29%29%3B%0A%2F%2F%20%3A%3A%20%7Btype%3A%20%5BType%5D%7D%20-%3E%20String%0Aconst%20topLevelName%20%3D%20pipe%28topLevel%2C%20propOr%28%27NoName%27%2C%20%27name%27%29%29%3B%0A%2F%2F%20%3A%3A%20%5B%7Btitle%3A%20String%2C%20type%3A%20%5BType%7D%5D%7D%5D%20-%3E%20%5BType%5D%0Aconst%20extract2ndLevel%20%3D%20pipe%28pluck%28%27type%27%29%2C%20flatten%2C%20filter%28levelEq%282%29%29%29%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20%5B%7Btitle%3A%20String%2C%20type%3A%20%5BType%5D%7D%5D%20-%3E%20%5B%7Bname%3A%20String%2C%20typechild%3A%20%5BType%5D%7D%5D%0Aconst%20convert%20%3D%20pipe%28%0A%20%20groupBy%28topLevelName%29%2C%0A%20%20map%28extract2ndLevel%29%2C%0A%20%20map%28uniq%29%2C%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20map%28pluck%28%27name%27%29%29%2C%20%2F%2F%20uncomment%20to%20see%20another%20format%0A%20%20toPairs%2C%0A%20%20map%28zipObj%28%5B%27name%27%2C%20%27typechild%27%5D%29%29%0A%29%3B%0A%0Aconvert%28data%29%3B%0A)**.

Comment: Thank you - that is worthy of a blog post! with the "extract 2nd level" function, it should actually extract anything above level 2. How would I do this? I can see there are more graceful ways of doing it, but I want to test out all the examples.

Comment: It would be easy enough to build that using a slight variant of `levelEq` named `levelAtLeast` (perhaps `(n) => pipe(prop('level'), gte(__, n))`).  I saw that you suggested that, but your sample data didn't include any relevant items.  My only question would be that if you added, say, Russet, with types *Food*, *Vegetable*, and *Potato*, would *Potato* still show up in your output directly under *Food*?  Or is there some nested structure?

Comment: Yep , got it. Is there much of an advantage changing the data structure?
 I need to keep the `color` attribute, so listing in an array isn't idea unless there is a decent performance boost. Also, Looks like ` filter(pipe(prop('level'), gte(__, 2)))` has worked great! What if I wanted to say between level 2-4?

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you change your data structure.  The `color` attribute simply wasn't relevant to the discussion.  Adding it back should not change anything.  And that's the only thing I changed, I believe.  I don't know what you mean by "listing it in an array".  It's easy enough to write a 2 - 4, although at that point it's probably best not to go point-free.  `(n) => n >= 2 && n n <= 4`

Comment: Hi, you helped me a lot with this one :) It just has one issue, where it only returns the first array. I opened a new question- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46845461/