# Ramda to loop over array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, reduce, ramda.js

Loop may be the wrong term, but it kind of describes what I am attempting.
I want to give structure to flat data, but I also need to keep track of the array it came from.

Basically my rules are (per array):

1. If level 1 exists- give it the `name` of the item, and a `typechild` array. EACH time a level 1 appears (even in the same array) it should create a new entry.
2. Inside `typechild`, put the any items with level >1
3. If NO level 1 exists- give it the `name` of the item, and a `typechild` array.

My code below is *almost* there, with the exception that it should create an array EVERYTIME it sees a level 1. My example will make sense:

**Input data**

```
 [
  {
    "title": "Test 1",
    "type": [{
        "name": "Animal",
        "level": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "Food",
        "level": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "Chicken",
        "level": 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Test 2",
    "type": [{
      "name": "Foo",
      "level": 2
    }]
  }
]
```

**Note: Animal and Food are both LEVEL 1 items. So it should create two ARRAYS like so...**

**Desired output**

```
[
    {
        name: "Animal",
        typechild: [
            {
                level: 2,
                name: "Chicken"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Food",
        typechild: [
            {
                level: 2,
                name: "Chicken"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "NoName",
        typechild: [
            {
                level: 2,
                name: "Foo"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Ramda attempt (try here: https://dpaste.de/JQHw):

```
const levelEq = (n) => pipe(prop('level'), equals(n));
const topLevel = pipe(prop('type'), find(levelEq(1)));
const topLevelName = pipe(topLevel, propOr('NoName', 'name'));
const extract2ndLevel = pipe(pluck('type'), flatten, filter(levelEq(2)));

const convert = pipe(
  groupBy(topLevelName),
  map(extract2ndLevel),
  map(uniq),
  toPairs,
  map(zipObj(['name', 'typechild']))
);
```

Comment: Why is `Chicken` level 2? Where does `NoName` come from?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```js
var output = [{
  "name": "Animal",
  "typechild": [{
    "name": "Chicken",
    "level": 3
  }, {
    "name": "Dog",
    "level": 2
  }]
}, {
  "name": "Food",
  "typechild": [{
    "name": "Chicken",
    "level": 3
  }]
}, {
  "name": "No name",
  "typechild": [{
    "name": "Foo",
    "level": 2
  }, {
    "name": "Baz",
    "level": 2
  }]
}]


let out = {},
  typechild = {},
  k;

const data = [{
  "title": "Test 1",
  "type": [{
    "name": "Animal",
    "level": 1
  }, {
    "name": "Food",
    "level": 1
  }, {
    "name": "Chicken",
    "level": 3
  }]
}, {
  "title": "Test 2",
  "type": [{
    "name": "Foo",
    "level": 2
  }]
}, {
  "title": "Test 3",
  "type": [{
    "name": "Baz",
    "level": 2
  }]
}, {
  "title": "Test 4",
  "type": [{
    "name": "Animal",
    "level": 1
  }, {
    "name": "Dog",
    "level": 2
  }]
}]


data.forEach((node) => {
  k = false;
  typechild[node.title] = [];
  node.type && node.type.forEach((t, i) => {
    if (t.level == 1) {
      k = true;

      !out[t.name] ? out[t.name] = {
        name: t.name,
        typechild: typechild[node.title]
      } : out[t.name].typechild = out[t.name].typechild.concat(typechild[node.title]);
    } else {
      typechild[node.title].push(t);
    }
    if (i == node.type.length - 1 && !k && typechild[node.title].length) {
      out['No name'] = out['No name'] || {
        name: 'No name',
        typechild: []
      };

      out['No name'].typechild = out['No name'].typechild.concat(typechild[node.title]);
    }
  });
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.values(out)));
```

Comment: That doesn't quite do it- the typechild: values are displaying a wierd ` "typechild": /**ref:3**/` like values. Could you confirm the typechild part is correct?

Comment: Test in your console. Here it complains abut same reference.

Comment: Thanks, but keep getting undefined! Tried it here- https://jsfiddle.net/7pzqb2q2/

Comment: Man.... you are not loging the out var where I store the result.  https://jsfiddle.net/7pzqb2q2/2/

Comment: Oh yep. I should have also made it clear- the `No name` array should be just one array (combined). How woudl that get done? Sample here https://jsfiddle.net/7pzqb2q2/4/

Comment: In fact, all top level tags should be unique- IE all items under the one level 1 array (example data here at the top- https://jsfiddle.net/7pzqb2q2/6/)

Comment: Thanks- but not quite there yet! It only seems to take the first "top level" item it sees. It doesn't combine it with the others. See my example (with desired output) here: https://jsfiddle.net/7pzqb2q2/20/