# Combine matching object arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, arr

I am trying do combine the nested objects inside items with the same key.

- Find 'top level' values that are duplicated,
- Combine the duplicated 'top level' items into one object (including their children.
- There should be no duplicate values inside the 'type' arrays

I tried it here https://jsfiddle.net/Lpq6huvw/410/

Input data:

```
[{
    "a": "Mon",
    "type": [{
        "b": 1
    }, {
        "b": 3
    }]
}, {
    "a": "Mon",
    "type": [{
        "b": 2
    }]
}, {
    "a": "Tue",
    "type": [{
        "b": 40
    }]
}, {
    "a": "Tue",
    "type": [{
        "b": 50
    }]
}, {
    "a": "Wed",
    "type": [{
        "b": 30
    }]
}]
```

Into this array:

```
    [{
      "a": "Mon",
      "type": [{
        "b": 1
      }, {
        "b": 3
      },
      {
        "b": 2
      }]
    }, 
    {
      "a": "Tue",
      "type": [{
        "b": 40
      },
      {
        "b": 50
      }]
    }, {
      "a": "Wed",
      "type": [{
        "b": 30
      }]
    }]
```

I attempted this below, which maps all the duplicated items as ONE object. However, I want it to map each under its' 'top level' predecessor.

```
const z = _.uniqBy(_.filter(data.map(e=>e.a), v => _.filter(data.map(e=>e.a), v1 => v1 === v).length > 1))
const dupes = data.filter(itm => z.includes(itm.a))

const flat = _.flatMap(dupes, item => 
                        _(item.type)
                          .map(v => ({b: v.b}))
                          .value()
)
```

Comment: Will the property names always be the same, with just values changing?

Comment: Yep they will remain the same

Comment: *"There should be no duplicate values inside the 'type' arrays"* - Do you mean that the input will never have duplicated `type` values, or that the input might have duplicates but the output should not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally find Javascript's built in functions work nice, and seem easier to follow than some of lodash functions.

eg.

```js
var data = [{"a":"Mon","type":[{"b":1},{"b":3}]},{"a":"Mon","type":[{"b":2},{"b":3}]},{"a":"Tue","type":[{"b":40}]},{"a":"Tue","type":[{"b":50}]},{"a":"Wed","type":[{"b":30}]}];

    
var result = data.reduce((acc, val) => {
  var found = acc.find((findval) => val.a === findval.a);
  if (!found) acc.push(val)
  else found.type = found.type.concat(
    val.type.filter((f) => !found.type.find((findval) => f.b === findval.b)));
  return acc;
}, []);
 
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Great- minimal implementation. Just a little confused as to why data was named `var a` then it returns `a`. Either way- it works!

Comment: `a` in the return is the accumulator in reduce function.  I'll rename some of the vars to prevent the confusion.

Comment: FYI I'm combining it with this solution from another question- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46845461

Comment: @Ycon  I've update the variable names, I think it makes it easier to follow.  Should have done that in the first place, I was just been lazy.. :)

Comment: Ah, it has a problem as it is not making the nested items unique on "name" as it should be. How would it do that?

Comment: When you say name, do you mean the property `b`?.

Comment: Yes, property `b` should not be duplicated

Answer (score 1):

Here's a answer w/o lodash:

```
function combine (input) {
  const hash = input.reduce((result, current) => {
    if (result[current['a']]) {
      result[current['a']] = result[current['a']].concat(current['type'])
    } else {
      result[current['a']] = current['type']
    }

    return result
  }, {})

  return Object.keys(hash).map(key => {
    return {
      a: key,
      type: hash[key]
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**ES6**: you can iterate with Array#reduce, collect the items into a Map, and then convert back to an array with the spread syntax and Map#values:

```js
const data = [{"a":"Mon","type":[{"b":1},{"b":3}]},{"a":"Mon","type":[{"b":2}]},{"a":"Tue","type":[{"b":40}]},{"a":"Tue","type":[{"b":50}]},{"a":"Wed","type":[{"b":30}]}];

const result = [...data.reduce((m, { a, type }) => {
  const item = m.get(a) || { a, type: [] }; // use a Set to maintain uniqueness
  
  item.type.push(...type);
  
  return m.set(a, item);
}, new Map).values()]
.map(({ a, type }) => ({ // make types unique again
  a, 
  type: [...type.reduce((m, o) => m.has(o.b) ? m : m.set(o.b, o), new Map).values()]
}));


console.log(result);
```

**Lodash**: Use `_.groupBy()` to get all objects with the same `a` property in one group. Map the groups, and merge each group using `_.mergeWith()`, and concat all `type` arrays.
Make another pass with map to make all items in `type` arrays unique.

```js
const data = [{"a":"Mon","type":[{"b":1},{"b":3}]},{"a":"Mon","type":[{"b":2}]},{"a":"Tue","type":[{"b":40}]},{"a":"Tue","type":[{"b":50}]},{"a":"Wed","type":[{"b":30}]}];


const result = _(data)
  .groupBy('a')
  .map((group) => _.mergeWith({}, ...group, ((objValue, srcValue, key) =>
    key === 'type' ? (objValue || []).concat(srcValue) : undefined
  )))
  .map((obj) => Object.assign(obj, { type: _.uniq(obj.type) }))
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thansk for those- but neither seems to show multiple items inside of the `b` proprety. Could you chceck?